# Slow excel document verbose status

Tags: microsoft-excel, performance, logging, debug

I have inherited a set of large poorly optimised excel documents used to post process outputs from a bespoke matlab simulator and they are so slow. They're slow to open, recalculate, and save; and using them just makes them slower (up to 45 minutes to open/save). I have been allowed to optimise them to make them run better, but specifically not allowed to burn them to the ground and start again. I have already gone for the low hanging fruit and improved the formatting, removed redundant formulas and corrected, removed or caught any errors.

Is there a way I can enable some kind of debug or verbose logging to see where the process is taking so long. Then I can focus my efforts rather than chasing minimal gain.

Comment: Does it use VBA?

Comment: You could try using the FastExcel add-in from Decision Models. This is not proposed as an answer because it is a product recommendation, but they do offer a free 15 day trial licence so you could see if it would work for you. I have no affiliation with Decision Models, although I have met the product's author Charles Williams and seen him speak at conferences a couple of times.

Comment: About half of them have no VBA at all, and the other half have very simple single function subs such as FillDown and ClearContents.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no there is no performance logging or debug output in Excel.
You can run the timer function in VBA code to time the execution of various VBA subs or functions or macros (but not Excel recalculations directly).

My top tips for optimising the speed of your Excel workbook:

1. **Compare workbook data size** (columns, rows, sheets) and filesize. A disproportionately large file might have some hidden diagrams or drawings that take up large chunks of memory. You can rename .xlsx to .zip, then unzip into a folder and look for the largest file to give you a hint.
2. **Save as different file types**, e.g. old .xls save to new .xlsx, new .xlsx to binary .xlsb. This is especially helpful with long loading and saving times of large data sets.
3. **Check CPU and memory usage**. High memory usage without much CPU movement would indicate  its mostly just a lot of data, but not really processing intensive. Binary format (.xlsb) coupled with RAM (double your ram) and disk (SSD) upgrades will help. Also check you auto-saving/backup settings to reduce the number of times the files are saved/backed-up while working on them.
4. If **CPU and memory usage** are high, chances are you have to climb into the formulae to optimise. Another indication of intensive formulae calcs would be a sudden and massive slow-down after say editing one of the early input cells, while relatively fast during viewing only (bar the initial loading time).
5. **VOLATILE functions** (OFFSET, INDIRECT, NOW, RAND, etc) is the death of any large spreadsheet. You can check for them by editing a blank, unreferenced, lonely cell down at the bottom. If this edit initiates several delays, volatile functions are likely to blame. Oh and don't forget **CONDITIONAL FORMATTING** IS VOLATILE too.
6. **VOLATILE triggers** include actions that cause a (spread)sheet wide recalc such as changing auto-filters, adjusting cell widths and heights, goal seek, hiding/unhiding/insertions/ deletions/moves/renames (of cells and sheets), refreshing connections to e.g. CSV files or DBs, changing named cells and ranges. If any of these are also executed in VBA macros, you got it.
7. **RECALCULATION SETTINGS** can majorly influence performance. If possible switch off auto-recalculation and recalculate manual after updates/editing. Avoid iterative calculations.
8. **Trace dependents/precendents** using the options on the Formulas ribbon, or using CTRL+[ and CTRL+]. The latter is quite useful as you can press CTRL+[ multiple times and you can determine dependents of dependents of dependents. They are actually selected as you go along (in contrast to the arrows added by the buttons on the ribbon) and can be colour coded/tagged as you like.
9. **Show or find troublesome formulae.** You can toggle Formulas ribbon > **Show formulas** (CTRL+~), to easily spot troublesome formulae. You can also do a workbook wide **find** for volatile functions, e.g. search for OFFSET.
10. **Don't forget the named ranges.** Check the name manager for named ranges that contain volatile functions.
11. Go **NON-VOLATILE**. Replace INDIRECT with INDEX(..MATCH(..)) and OFFSET with relative named ranges (such as a "CellAbove" named range)
12. **Data-memory optimisation.** Reduce the **USED RANGE** (no blank rows and columns inside your used range). Avoid cross referencing to other workbooks or even other sheets. Avoid storing data as text. Make sure it is numbered data. Avoid imaginary numbers as those are actually stored as text. If you have office 365, use LET to avoid recalculating the same piece of a formula over and over again. E.g. `=IF(LOG(A1)>B1,LOG(A1),B1)` can rather be `=LET(x, LOG(A1), IF(x > B1, x, B1))`. Also, if different cells do the same part of an equation over and over, rather calculate that in a separate cell or define named.
13. **Optimise you macros/VBA code/javascript**. Switch off recalculation/screen updates/events at the start of each sub or function call. Run the rest of the code and switch those back on again.
14. Use **block cell read and writes**. This is especially true in VBA/macro/javascript code. Individual cell access is slow, especially if screen updates are on. Try to accumulate your answers in an array and block write that back into the cells. Related to this, you can use array formulas (and spilling in Excel 365) to do the equivalent of block r/w's in Excel formulae. I have not verified if this is actually faster but my gut says yes.
15. **Check data connections.** Some connection are set to auto-update if you open the workbook, which can drastically increase overall loading times, especially when refreshing online / network data.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. I had tried the first few already with limited success but 5 looks like it may be the answer. The entire sheet is based on OFFSET and FORECAST functions, easily over 5 million of them. I'll try replacing them in a few simple locations and see if it gets any quicker.

Comment: That's definitely the problem (or at least one of the major ones). OFFSET is typically used with forecast or average etc to achieve a flexible number of values to compute over i.e. forecast using the last 5 values, then change dynamically to the last 6 values. `=FORECAST(A10, OFFSET(B10,-5,0,5), OFFSET(A10,-5,0,5))` can be written like this instead `=FORECAST(A10, B10:INDEX(B1:B10,COUNTA(B1:B10)+1 - 5),  A10:INDEX(A1:A10,COUNTA(A1:A10)+1 - 5))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the Workbook uses VBA, and post an answer based on this assumption.

The majority of the cost will be in refreshing the screen, and/or writing the file to disk/a network share.

For the screen refreshing, wrap the module which is doing the heavy lifting in

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Do Something
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

These settings make it look like nothing is happening, but the code-behind will still be executing. You could add some `debug.print`'s in and monitor your immediate window to confirm where you're up to.

You could also look at disabling `Application.EnableEvents`, and only use `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` where absolutely necessary.

With respect to disk cost. I would encourage you (if you're not already) to put the file on your local machine, and if possible the source MatLab data. Reading/writing to/from network shares is inherently slow, vs local disk.