# Dynamic Array Subtotal that changes its column sizes without using VBA or volatile functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365, array

I need to make a dynamic array subtotal that changes its column size by another dynamic array. The example sheet, challenge, conditions, and attempts I've made are below.

[[Example Sheet]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDRyo.png)

Challenge:

- Make (partial) dynamic subtotal arrays in column D fully dynamic that change their column sizes by another dynamic array
- Modify the range part $C$10:$L$28 in the dynamic subtotal arrays using D5# (helping array)
- It should be a generic formula that copy-paste is available within column D; there will be thousands of criteria 1 and 2 in column A and B
- Avoid using VBA, volatile functions (OFFSET, INDIRECT, INFO, CELL, etc.) or other expensive methods

Pre-requisites:

- Project start/end dates determine the size of the dynamic array D6# (Month-Year)
- D6# is used for the dynamic array D7# (Workhours/month)
- D5# is an helping array to determine the size of the dynamic array subtotals
- Criteria 1 and 2 in column A and B are used for the dynamic array subtotals
  -The formula should be not broken when rows are added or deleted; users will add or delete rows and edit the criteria
- The dynamic array subtotals sum up the monthly workhours per each criteria 1 and 2

Attempts:

- SUBTOTAL can be only dynamic to show AVERAGE, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, etc. I couldn't think of any way to utilize this function.
- Formula: `=SUBTOTAL(SEQUENCE(11),reference range)`
- SUMIFS can be dynamic if the criteria ranges are dynamic, which is not the way I wanted; it needs to use a dynamic array to determine the column size. What I have is non-dynamic formula that requires manual copy to the rest columns. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69655057/can-one-do-a-sumifs-on-a-dynamic-spilled-range-and-return-a-2d-array)
- Formula: `=SUMIFS(D:D,$A:$A,$A10,$B:$B,TEXTBEFORE($B10," Subtotal"))`
- MMULT, TRANSPOSE and FILTER combo is the closest solution I came up with, which is partially dynamic that doesn't change its column size automatically. As mentioned above, the range $D$8:$L$26 is the tricky part to modify that somehow it refers to the helping array D5# without using OFFSET, INDIRECT or other volatile functions. At this stage, I need to manually set the formula the range to be summed up. ([Excel365 Sumifs with Spilled Dynamic Arrays](https://superuser.com/questions/1713274/excel365-sumifs-with-spilled-dynamic-arrays))
- Formula: `=LET(Criteria,($A$8:$A$26=A10)*($B$8:$B$26=TEXTBEFORE($B10," Subtotal")), MMULT(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Criteria,Criteria=1)),--FILTER($D$8:$L$26,Criteria=1)))`
- I'm trying to make the template VBA-free as users can be creative to break the macros in old templates I made. It was also time-consuming to build and maintain the code.

Much appreciated if you can suggest a solution to the struggle I'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here, but if I've understood you correctly, the following formula should work:

```
=LET(
arr, $D$7#:A10,
_c1, CHOOSECOLS(arr, 1),
_c2, CHOOSECOLS(arr, 2),
incl, (_c1=A10)*(_c2=TEXTBEFORE(B10, " Subtotal")),
BYCOL(FILTER(DROP(arr,, 3), incl), LAMBDA(c, SUM(c))))
```

This method utilizes a little known trick with dynamic arrays, whereby the range operator (colon) is used to extend the dimensions of `$D$7#` to include everything between it and cell `A10`. Basically, the resulting array is referencing *FROM* the minimum column (A) and minimum row (7) of the two ranges *TO* the maximum column (dynamic) and maximum row (10) of the two ranges (which is `A7:L10` in this example). **Note:** the reason I've used an absolute range reference with the dynamic array is so the formula can be copied and pasted in column D for each subtotal row.

`CHOOSECOLS()` is used to identify each criteria column, and `DROP()` is used to identify the data range by removing the first 3 columns. `BYCOL()` is then used to dynamically `SUM()` each column of the filtered array (so your "helping array" in cell `D5` is no longer needed).

**Results:**

[image: bycol_subtotals.png]

I hope that's what you meant. Cheers!