# Inserting 1000 rows to Table Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large table with approx 110 calculated columns and one row as a template, to which users paste a certain amount of rows - this ranges from anywhere between 30 and 200'000.

The way I do this is by having them run a macro to paste values to the first empty cell.
It seems like excel first automatically resizes the table and then pastes values.

**The resizing of the table is what takes the longest time, and I am trying to find an efficient way of doing it.**
To confirm the theory I wrote a Macro to just insert blank rows, and it seems to be slowing down exponentially, with every new row that is being added.
Also, pasting a clean set of values over the already inserted rows goes super fast (relatively to the initial paste)

Disabling automatic calculations and calculating everything at the end does not work, **the resizing still takes ages.**

Does anyone have any ideas? What would be the right way of doing this.

(For reasons too long to explain here calculated columns in PowerPivot would not work as an alternative, and rewriting every formula in DAX for a custom Pivot Table is also not sustainable at this stage, so I am really hoping to find a solution to be able to continue working with Tables).

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!!!

Comment: It would be useful to see your code

Comment: Try; 1. insert empty rows at top, then 2. paste copies of data/formulas. Any difference?

Comment: I suspect the problem lies with the Excel table. If you insert new rows in a table, Excel automatically pulls down the adjacent formulae, updates pivot tables and charts. Do you have to use a table? If so, and since you are using a macro to paste anyway, why not remove the table first, paste into normal excel, then format as table and reapply any formula?

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to try optimising the workbook (i.e. avoid volatile functions like OFFSET, INDIRECT and NOW; save as binary xlsb; work with computer set to English). Some more tips here https://superuser.com/questions/1643437/slow-excel-document-verbose-status/1643467#1643467

Comment: cybernetic.nomad - there is no real "code" to see I can paste some example formulae if it helps, though they will not mean anything without the underlying data which is confidential - there are a lot of formualae that divide a row value by a column total though

Hannu, I wrote a macro to insert empty rows before pasting, but after inserting the 1000th row it started becoming very slow

@Mobus - sounds like an A W E S O M E idea, will try and report back. The optimisation tips I have already exploited before posting this :)

Comment: Are you using any whole column references? E.g. see here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/excel-takes-long-time-to-insert-delete-rows

Comment: @Mobus, that was indeed what I was afraid of... And yes I am using a lot of whole column references.

So, what I did try is replacing = with ### in the formulas and adding the rows - even as a table that was not a problem.

Then I copy pasted the one row with the "deactivated" formulas to the rest of the sheet - also no problem.

When converting them back to formulas though Excel could not cope.

I will now rewrite the sheet as a regular range... bye bye efficient macro and formula writing...

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You can replace whole column references like $A:$A with non-volatile dynamic **named** ranges (Formulas ribbon > Define Name) like `=$A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))`. The idea to used it as a named range is that the large array $A:$A will only be loaded to memory once (and not recalculate all the time). If you have to use it without a named range, its probably better to use it with LET in the formula, or limit the range `$A$1:INDEX($A$1:$A$100000,COUNTA($A$1:$A$100000))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened on this very detailed explanation of both the problem and the solution:

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/fix-slow-pasting-to-excel-tables

Key to this method is that the blank rows/columns are inserted with a single command, so no formula updates occur in between inserts. It may help to also disable automatic recalculation in VBA (`Application.Calculation = xlManual` ) before the insertion, then reenable it at the end just *before* enabling screen updates(`Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` ). This is not in SpreadsheetGuru's code and should be added.

I provide spreadsheetguru's code here for completeness. I have not tested this code myself. It might clear/overwrite old data in the table so make your backups first. All credit to TheSpreadsheetGuru.

```
Sub ResizeAndPasteToTable()
'PURPOSE: Resize ActiveTable Based on Copied Data and PasteValues Only
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim myClipboard As Object
Dim ActiveTable As ListObject
Dim TableSize As Range
Dim TableName As String
Dim ClipboardData As String
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ColumnCount As Long
Dim TableRows As Long
Dim TableColumns As Long
Dim RowDifference As Long
Dim ColumnDifference As Long
Dim UserAnswer As Long
Dim HeaderAdjuster As Integer
Dim x As Integer

'Ensure Data is copied
  If Application.CutCopyMode <> xlCopy And Application.CutCopyMode <> xlCut Then
    MsgBox "Please copy data to the clipboard before running this."
    Exit Sub
  End If

'Determine if ActiveCell is inside a Table
  On Error GoTo NoTableSelected
    TableName = ActiveCell.ListObject.Name
    Set ActiveTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(TableName)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Ask User if they Copied Table Headings
  UserAnswer = MsgBox("Does your copied data include table headings?", vbYesNoCancel)

  Select Case UserAnswer
    Case vbYes: HeaderAdjuster = 0
    Case vbNo: HeaderAdjuster = 1
    Case vbCancel: Exit Sub
  End Select

'Turn Off ScreenUpdating
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create Data Object using MS Forms 2.0 Object Library (Late Binding)
  Set myClipboard = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

'Gather how many rows/columns to resize Table (based on Copied Range)
  myClipboard.GetFromClipboard
  ClipboardData = myClipboard.GetText
  
  RowCount = UBound(Split(ClipboardData, vbCrLf))
  ColumnCount = UBound(Split(Split(ClipboardData, vbCrLf)(0), vbTab)) + 1
  If RowCount = 0 Then Exit Sub

'Determine difference between copied data and table row count
  TableRows = ActiveTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
  TableColumns = ActiveTable.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count
  RowDifference = RowCount - TableRows
  ColumnDifference = ColumnCount - TableColumns

'Resize ActiveTable Rows (If Necessary)
  If RowDifference > 0 Then
    'Store desired new size to a Range Variable
      Set TableSize = Range(ActiveTable.Name & "[#All]"). _
        Resize(RowCount + HeaderAdjuster, TableColumns)
    
    'Resize Table
      ActiveTable.Resize TableSize
  End If

'Resize ActiveTable Rows (If Necessary)
  If ColumnDifference > 0 Then
    'Store desired new size to a Range Variable
      Set TableSize = Range(ActiveTable.Name & "[#All]"). _
        Resize(ActiveTable.Range.Rows.Count, ColumnCount)
    
    'Resize Table
      ActiveTable.Resize TableSize
  End If

'Paste Data into Table (Values Only)
  If UserAnswer = vbYes Then
    ActiveTable.Range.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Else
    ActiveTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  End If

'Reduce Table Row Count (if necessary)
  If RowDifference < 0 Then
    TableRows = ActiveTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    ActiveTable.DataBodyRange.Rows(TableRows + HeaderAdjuster + RowDifference & ":" & TableRows).Delete
  End If

'Reduce Table Column Count (if necessary)
  If ColumnDifference < 0 Then
    TableColumns = ActiveTable.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count
    For x = 1 To -ColumnDifference
      ActiveTable.Range.Columns(TableColumns + ColumnDifference + 1).Delete
    Next x
  End If

'Clear Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = msoFalse
  Exit Sub


'ERROR HANDLERS
NoTableSelected:
  MsgBox "There is no Table currently selected!", vbCritical

End Sub
```

Comment: you are a legend!!! I adapted the code, but it will resize the table to 140 cols x 200K rows in a minute, while the other paste was taking close to 30!!! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Glad it worked! Did you add `Application.Calculation = xlManual / xlAutomatic` to your code? I'm curious to know if it makes a difference.

Comment: I am still working on it. I added it yes, and once I can get the code to run I can tell you how much of a difference it makes.

I do have an issue now though where the   Clipboarddata = Myclipboard.GetText fails... Trying to figure out why

Comment: Funnily enough, it is this manual calculation step that breaks the process... My guess is that it triggers clearing of the clipboard, as the error message I was getting seems to be related to having an empty clipboard. Now that I removed it the code works.

I am trying to see if I can temporarily save the clipboard in a new sheet, then disable calculations, resize, and then copy paste... Reporting back in a few mins

Comment: So, on a small dataset it runs great! Trying it now with the 200K row dataset

Comment: Could be, TheSpreadsheetGuru's article mentions something about the Excel clipboard being cleared when you delete a row or column. I think if you put `Application.Calculation = xlManual` **before** `myClipboard.GetFromClipboard` you should be good.

Comment: That is what I had - it did not work - but my workaround fixed it. Happy to report that 233'864 rows were pasted to a table with 131 calculated columns in under 5 mins, using a standard business laptop with a Ryzen5 Pro 4650U chip.

You sir, are amazing! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: No problem! Looks like its a known issue: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/applicationcalculation-state-change-clears/46cd5a0e-bb8c-48ae-b7c6-bb5578296009

Comment: Opting to replace formulas by values after the stuff has been pasted on the table was a bad idea... it basically runs through the whole loop again, even if it is done as an array